Random process Channel Bandwidth needed
A stationary random process has a normalized power of 60 units.
and the random process never exceeds 6 in magnitude. Determine the number of
quantization levels to guarantee an SQNR of at least 60dB. What is the minimum
channel bandwidth required, if the bandwidth of the signal is 6kHz.

Welcome to our stack exchange. We don't give full answers to homework questions. Please show your work so far and tell us where exactly you are stuck.
